# Should I reject an edit consisting only of import lines removal in Java code?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I am new to the review queue, and not sure about the consensus on this kind of edits:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18082015

Basically, there was about 10 `import` and `package` statements that were deleted (no other changes).

I am not a Java or Android person, but it is clear that some of them are required for the code to run.

In a sense, it is maybe making the code clearer for the SO user & Android developer. Most of these imports are basic and should be considered maybe obvious and are just noise in the actual question. They can be probably automatically added from any IDE anyway.

However, it seems to me that we insist a lot on askers to create an MCVE in their question. Removing necessary lines is not helping creating an MCVE at all, maybe some of theses deleted statements are not obvious.

I have skipped the review, but, in the future, should I tend to accept or reject those edits?